# BeautifulSoup table to dataframe

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

Can't seem to copy over the values from the table into a dataframe correctly. If you run raw_data, it outputs a list of all the values. Any idea how to make it structured?

```
pop_source = requests.get("http://zipatlas.com/us/tx/austin/zip-code-comparison/population-density.htm").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(pop_source, 'html5lib')    
source = soup.find_all('td',class_ = 'report_data')


pop = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Zip Code','Population'])


row_data = [data.text for data in source]

temp_df = pd.DataFrame([row_data], columns=['#','Zip Code','Location','City', 'Population','People/Sq.Mile','National Rank'])   

temp_df = temp_df[['Zip Code','Population']]   
pop = pop.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)    
pop
```

Comment: what do you mean there's 8 columns? I only see 7 on the site.

Comment: you also have `'Population'` in there twice `temp_df = pd.DataFrame([row_data], columns=['Zip Code','Location','City', 'Population', 'People/Sq.Mile','Population','National Rank'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things with the code:

1. The code you have above actually doesn't loop through anything. In fact if you try to run this you should be getting tons of errors. There's no way to see that output of just looping same values with what you provided.
2. The indentation is off,
3. you reference a variable `source` which hasn't been defined. You reference a variable `cols` which is also not defined.
4. You initialize a dataframe `pop` with 2 columns, and try to append a dataframe with 7 columns.

All kinds of issues happening here.

Have you considered just using straight up Pandas to form the dataframe? You could still use BeautifulSoup, but pandas can do the work for you, and it seems like you need to get a little more practice of iterating through elements with BeautifulSoup (you actually never even used `.find` or `.find_all` to locate the tags associated with the table you want.)

If you NEED the BeautifulSoup way to do it, just let me know and I can offer that way as well, but honestly, it's a lot more work than just using the `.read_html()` with pandas here.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://zipatlas.com/us/tx/austin/zip-code-comparison/population-density.htm'

tables = pd.read_html(url)

df = tables[11][1:]
df.columns = tables[11].iloc[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
0     # Zip Code      ...      People / Sq. Mile National Rank
1    1.    78705      ...               11008.66          #519
2    2.    78751      ...                5822.28        #1,374
3    3.    78752      ...                5435.92        #1,528
4    4.    78741      ...                5346.47        #1,562
5    5.    78723      ...                5175.95        #1,640
6    6.    78704      ...                5001.96        #1,713
7    7.    78758      ...                4954.80        #1,730
8    8.    78702      ...                4501.98        #2,015
9    9.    78757      ...                4380.92        #2,087
10  10.    78756      ...                4298.80        #2,139
11  11.    78745      ...                4063.22        #2,295
12  12.    78753      ...                3973.96        #2,350
13  13.    78703      ...                3491.54        #2,753
14  14.    78731      ...                3031.63        #3,167
15  15.    78759      ...                2998.68        #3,199
16  16.    78727      ...                2856.67        #3,371
17  17.    78749      ...                2795.02        #3,438
18  18.    78728      ...                2640.31        #3,614
19  19.    78721      ...                2568.43        #3,690
20  20.    78722      ...                2567.53        #3,692
21  21.    78729      ...                2366.94        #3,944
22  22.    78701      ...                2326.65        #3,995
23  23.    78748      ...                1961.73        #4,504
24  24.    78750      ...                1731.01        #4,870
25  25.    78744      ...                1464.78        #5,311
26  26.    78746      ...                1152.39        #5,971
27  27.    78717      ...                1081.05        #6,119
28  28.    78739      ...                 768.80        #7,006
29  29.    78734      ...                 698.96        #7,267
30  30.    78724      ...                 555.85        #7,870
31  31.    78726      ...                 543.24        #7,940
32  32.    78733      ...                 510.92        #8,116
33  33.    78754      ...                 484.73        #8,255
34  34.    78735      ...                 474.14        #8,318
35  35.    78732      ...                 416.13        #8,702
36  36.    78742      ...                 321.40        #9,467
37  37.    78730      ...                 257.86       #10,189
38  38.    78738      ...                 213.29       #10,829
39  39.    78747      ...                 194.02       #11,173
40  40.    78736      ...                 187.88       #11,301
41  41.    78737      ...                 143.90       #12,372
42  42.    78725      ...                 116.87       #13,282
43  43.    78719      ...                  93.88       #14,377

[43 rows x 7 columns]
```

**with BeautifulSoup**

This is not the ideal way to do this. While this site is pretty straight forward with the `table`, `tr`, `td` tags. What you probably would want is first grab all the rows, then iterate through each row to grab the `<td>` tags. But you grabbed all the `<td>` tags in one big swoop. Which is still ok, but we would need to break that up into each row.

All I did was then break that up into groups of 7, since that's how many columns there are. Note, I'm making a huge assumption all the data is there. If it's not, then the table would be off or rows, columns would be shifted.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import bs4


# Create a function called "chunks" with two arguments, l and n:
def chunks(l, n):
    # For item i in a range that is a length of l,
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        # Create an index range for l of n items:
        yield l[i:i+n]



pop_source = requests.get("http://zipatlas.com/us/tx/austin/zip-code-comparison/population-density.htm").text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pop_source, 'html5lib')


source = soup.find_all('td',class_ = 'report_data')

pop = pd.DataFrame(columns=['#','Zip Code','Location','City', 'Population','People/Sq.Mile','National Rank'])

row_data = [data.text for data in source]

rows_data = list(chunks(row_data, 7))

for ele in rows_data:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([ele], columns=['#','Zip Code','Location','City', 'Population','People/Sq.Mile','National Rank'])
    pop = pop.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: See the updated post. I've used the same method you recommend before. It's definitely easier. But I'm just trying to get the hang of using BS. Right now I pretty much have a list of all the values from the table, and am trying to figure out how to structure it into a dataframe. Also, sorry, I keep deleting parts of my code when editing on here. It should be all good now.

Comment: cool. Can you copy that code EXACTLY how you have it to get that list? And btw, I'm not trying to be critical, just helping out. It is tricky so definitely the more examples/practice the easier it gets

Comment: I was trying to use the same function. I was trying to use it after getting the list of data and then transforming it into a dataframe, but the way you did it was a little easier. I appreciate the help

Comment: I also add, no obligation either. You are more than welcome to keep working at it and posting on SO too. It’s just if you’re still not quite getting it or feel completely stuck

Comment: Awesome, if you find a good example, feel free to email me at cubsrocker94@gmail.com