# Obtaining \r\n\r\n while scraping from web in Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am workin on scraping text using Python from the link; [tournament link](https://www.hubertiming.com/results/2017GPTR10K)

Here is my code to get the tabular data;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.hubertiming.com/results/2017GPTR10K"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find_all('tr') ## find the table rows
```

Now, the goal is to obtain the data as a dataframe.

```
listnew=[]
for row in rows:
    row_td = row.find_all('td')
    str_cells = str(row_td)
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text() ##obtain text part
    listnew.append(cleantext) ## append to list

df = pd.DataFrame(listnew)
df.head(10)
```

Then we get following output;

```
0   []
1   [Finishers:, 577]
2   [Male:, 414]
3   [Female:, 163]
4   []
5   [1, 814, \r\n\r\n JARED WIL...
6   [2, 573, \r\n\r\n NATHAN A ...
7   [3, 687, \r\n\r\n FRANCISCO...
8   [4, 623, \r\n\r\n PAUL MORR...
9   [5, 569, \r\n\r\n DEREK G O..
```

I don't know why there is a new line character and carriage return character; `\r\n\r\n`? how can I remove them and get a dataframe in the proper format? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your `import`s, Where is `urlopen` exactly from?

Comment: Please see the edits. I did add `import` statements.

Comment: Do you know how to remove characters from a string?

Comment: hi, if you want to be a purist and not use any extra libraries you can call `.strip()` on the array element ant to strip whitespace and unprintable characters from the beginning and end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas can parse HTML tables, give this a try:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.hubertiming.com/results/2017GPTR10K"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

table_1_html = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'individualResults'})

t_1 = pd.read_html(table_1_html.prettify())[0]

print(t_1)
```

Output:

```
     Place  Bib                Name  ... Chip Pace Gun Time          Team
0        1  814        JARED WILSON  ...      5:51    36:24           NaN
1        2  573  NATHAN A SUSTERSIC  ...      5:55    36:45  INTEL TEAM F
2        3  687      FRANCISCO MAYA  ...      6:05    37:48           NaN
3        4  623         PAUL MORROW  ...      6:13    38:37           NaN
4        5  569     DEREK G OSBORNE  ...      6:20    39:24  INTEL TEAM F
..     ...  ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...           ...
572    573  273      RACHEL L VANEY  ...     15:51  1:38:34           NaN
573    574  467      ROHIT B DSOUZA  ...     15:53  1:40:32  INTEL TEAM I
574    575  471      CENITA D'SOUZA  ...     15:53  1:40:34           NaN
575    576  338      PRANAVI APPANA  ...     16:15  1:42:01           NaN
576    577  443    LIBBY B MITCHELL  ...     16:20  1:42:10           NaN

[577 rows x 10 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some cells in the HTML code has a lot of leading and trailing spaces and new lines:

```html
<td>

                    JARED WILSON

                </td>
```

Use [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.strip) to remove all leading and trailing whitespace, like this:
`BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text().strip()`.

Comment: If there's also superfluous whitespace in the middle, you can do a regex replace; `WHITESPACE = re.compile(r'\s+')` at the top then `text = WHITESPACE.sub(' ', text.strip())` in the loop.

Comment: `WHITESPACE.sub(' ', text)` seems to do the trick. The string `[577, 443, \r\n\r\n                    LIBBY B MITCHELL\r\n\r\n                , F, HILLSBORO, OR, 1:41:18, 16:20, 1:42:10, ]` gets converted to `'[577, 443, LIBBY B MITCHELL , F, HILLSBORO, OR, 1:41:18, 16:20, 1:42:10, ]'`

Comment: @sabik Thanks for the advice. It seems `WHITESPACE.sub(' ', text.strip())` seems to be working. May I know how does it work. It will help me to learn sth. thanks

Comment: Right, I meant to apply it after splitting up the row, to deal with the possibility of extra spaces / newlines in the middle of the name (like `LIBBY\r\nB\r\nMITCHELL`).

Comment: How it works - this is a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) substitution; `\s+` means "any amount of whitespace" (`\s` means whitespace, `+` means one or more). The `sub()` method does a search and replace, so it searches for "any amount of whitespace" and replaces each of them with a single space. The `.compile()` is an optimisation, to translate the `\s+` into an internal form for faster processing; without that, it would be: `text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text.strip())`

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at the url you provided, you can see the new lines in the :

```html
...
<td>814</td>
<td>
JARED WILSON
</td>
...
```

so that's what you get when you scrape. These can easily be removed by the very convenient `.strip()` string method.

Your DataFrame is not formatted correctly because you are giving it a list of lists, which are not all of the same size (see the first 4 lines), which come from another table located on the top right. One easy fix is to remove the first 4 lines, though it would be way more robust to select the table you want based on its id (`"individualResults"`).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(listnew[4:])
df.head(10)
```

Have a look here: [BeautifulSoup table to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335078/beautifulsoup-table-to-dataframe)